# error deleting class array pointer

Tags: c++, windows

Trying to work out why i get a error when using delete on this array pointer?

Trying to load png images not sure whats going on

The error is when using `delete[] chunks;`

The code

```
typedef struct {
    char r;
    char g;
    char b;
    char a;
} pixel;

class chunk {
public:
    unsigned char length[4];
    unsigned char type[4];
    unsigned char* data;
    unsigned char CRC[4];

    ~chunk()
    {
        delete[] data;
    }
};

class PNG
{
public:
    PNG();
    PNG(std::string filename);
    ~PNG();
    void loadFile(std::string filename);
    pixel* get();
private:
    pixel * img;
    int width;
    int height;
    int bitdepth;
    int colourtype;
    int compressionmethod;
    int filtermethod;
    int interlacemethod;

    unsigned char* data;
    std::ifstream* file;

    int char2int(unsigned char* arr, int start);
};

void PNG::loadFile(std::string filename)
{
    file = new std::ifstream(filename.c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

    size_t size = 0;
    file->seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    size = file->tellg();
    file->seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    data = new unsigned char[size];
    file->read((char*)data, size);

    /*
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    std::cout << std::hex;
    std::cout.width(2);
    std::cout.fill('0');
    std::cout << (int)data[i] << std::endl;
    }
    */

    size_t index = 8; // ignore header
    chunk* chunks = new chunk[size];

    size_t chunkindex = 0;
    while (index < size) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            chunks[chunkindex].length[i] = data[index++];
        }
        std::cout << "Size of Chunk " << chunkindex + 1 << ": " << char2int(chunks[chunkindex].length, 0) << std::endl;
        chunks[chunkindex].data = new unsigned char[char2int(chunks[chunkindex].length, 0)];

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            chunks[chunkindex].type[i] = data[index++];
        }

        if (char2int(chunks[chunkindex].length, 0) != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < char2int(chunks[chunkindex].length, 0); i++) {
                chunks[chunkindex].data[i] = data[index++];
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            chunks[chunkindex].CRC[i] = data[index++];
        }

        chunkindex++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < chunkindex; i++) {
        char name[5];
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            name[j] = chunks[i].type[j];
        }
        name[4] = '\0';

        if (strcmp(name, "IHDR") == 0) {
            std::cout << "FOUND IHDR" << std::endl;
            width = char2int(chunks[i].data, 0);
            height = char2int(chunks[i].data, 4);
            bitdepth = chunks[i].data[8];
            colourtype = chunks[i].data[9];
            compressionmethod = chunks[i].data[10];
            filtermethod = chunks[i].data[11];
            interlacemethod = chunks[i].data[12];

        }
        else if (strcmp(name, "PLTE") == 0) {
            std::cout << "FOUND PLTE" << std::endl;
        }
        else if (strcmp(name, "IDAT") == 0) {
            std::cout << "FOUND IDAT" << std::endl;
        }
        else if (strcmp(name, "IEND") == 0) {
            std::cout << "FOUND IEND" << std::endl;
        }

    }


    std::cout << "Width: " << width << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Height: " << height << std::endl;

    delete[] chunks;
}
```

error:
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, your question is off topic without an MCVE.

Comment: 1) Please provide [mcve]. 2) "_The error is when using `delete[] chunks;`_" And the error is..? 3) Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: 1) As @AlgirdasPreidžius suggested, try using a debugger. If you are under Windows, I suggest Visual Community (free for a one-man project and very good at tracking memory issues.)    2) I also recommend you not to use raw allocations but containers or smart-pointers, in order to prevent memory leaks in case of exceptions... Have a look to the RAII principles [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii).

Comment: Regarding your edit: Not every `chunk::data` from `chunks` is initialized, due to multiple increments of `index` during the single iteration of the loop.

Comment: `index, chunkindex, size` - these 3 variables look very suspect. The loop limit is `index<size`, the array is dimensioned as `[size]` but accessed with `chunkindex` which is _not_ limited to `size`.

Comment: @MSalters Well, since `chunkindex` is incremented only once per loop, I fail to see how it can increase past `size`.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 5):

Add default constructor to your `chunk` class.

```
chunk::chunk () {
   data = 0;
}
```

When you call

```
    chunk* chunks = new chunk[size];
```

`size` objects were created and all created objected have junk data in `data` variable - this member is uninitialized. When you call

```
    delete[] chunks;
```

for each object of `chunks` array dtor is called, but when `data` member is not set - `delete[] data` is undefined behaviour.

`data` member was not set for all objects in your `chunks` array - see at your while loop: you allocate memory for `data` member in this line

```
        chunks[chunkindex].data = new unsigned char[char2int(chunks[chunkindex].length, 0)];
```

but not for all created objects because in your while loop per one iteration `index` is increased multiple times but `chunkindex` only once. When while loop is stopped by this contidion `index < size`, `chunkIndex` is not equal `size` it means there are chunk objects with unitialized `data` member.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use all those pointers in your code. For that application, in my opinion, you should resort to `std::vector` to help you with memory management. And, you *do* have a memory leak --- you are allocating `std::ifstream` object, and you are not releasing it with a matching `delete`. Well, maybe you are doing it in the destructor of `PNG`, which we do not see, but anyways you are not closing the file you have opened. You should release the resources (in this case, the opened file) back to the system.

For the code excerpt you pasted, maybe you should have something similar to the below, by changing the bare pointers to `std::vector`s and changing the `file` member to be an object rather than a pointer:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

typedef struct {
  char r;
  char g;
  char b;
  char a;
} pixel;

class chunk {
public:
  unsigned char length[4];
  unsigned char type[4];
  // unsigned char *data;
  /* let std::vector take care of memory issues */
  std::vector<unsigned char> data;
  unsigned char CRC[4];

  // ~chunk() { delete[] data; }
};

class PNG {
public:
  PNG();
  PNG(std::string filename);
  ~PNG();
  void loadFile(std::string filename);
  pixel *get();

private:
  // pixel *img;
  /* std::vector to the help */
  std::vector<pixel> img;
  int width;
  int height;
  int bitdepth;
  int colourtype;
  int compressionmethod;
  int filtermethod;
  int interlacemethod;

  /* please ! */
  // unsigned char *data;
  std::vector<unsigned char> data;
  // std::ifstream *file;
  /* you don't need a pointer here */
  std::ifstream file;

  int char2int(unsigned char *arr, int start);
};

void PNG::loadFile(std::string filename) {
  file = std::ifstream(filename, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

  /* better to check whether file is opened properly */
  // if (file) { ... }
  size_t size = 0;
  file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
  size = file.tellg();
  file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

  data = std::vector<unsigned char>(size);
  file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&data[0]), size);

  /* apparently you are done with the file */
  file.close();

  /*
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  std::cout << std::hex;
  std::cout.width(2);
  std::cout.fill('0');
  std::cout << (int)data[i] << std::endl;
  }
  */

  size_t index = 8; // ignore header
  std::vector<chunk> chunks(size);

  size_t chunkindex = 0;
  while (index < size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      chunks[chunkindex].length[i] = data[index++];
    }
    std::cout << "Size of Chunk " << chunkindex + 1 << ": "
              << char2int(chunks[chunkindex].length, 0) << std::endl;
    chunks[chunkindex].data =
        std::vector<unsigned char>(char2int(chunks[chunkindex].length, 0));

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      chunks[chunkindex].type[i] = data[index++];
    }

    if (char2int(chunks[chunkindex].length, 0) != 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < char2int(chunks[chunkindex].length, 0); i++) {
        chunks[chunkindex].data[i] = data[index++];
      }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      chunks[chunkindex].CRC[i] = data[index++];
    }

    chunkindex++;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < chunkindex; i++) {
    char name[5];
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      name[j] = chunks[i].type[j];
    }
    name[4] = '\0';

    if (strcmp(name, "IHDR") == 0) {
      std::cout << "FOUND IHDR" << std::endl;
      width = char2int(&(chunks[i].data[0]), 0);
      height = char2int(&(chunks[i].data[0]), 4);
      bitdepth = chunks[i].data[8];
      colourtype = chunks[i].data[9];
      compressionmethod = chunks[i].data[10];
      filtermethod = chunks[i].data[11];
      interlacemethod = chunks[i].data[12];

    } else if (strcmp(name, "PLTE") == 0) {
      std::cout << "FOUND PLTE" << std::endl;
    } else if (strcmp(name, "IDAT") == 0) {
      std::cout << "FOUND IDAT" << std::endl;
    } else if (strcmp(name, "IEND") == 0) {
      std::cout << "FOUND IEND" << std::endl;
    }
  }

  std::cout << "Width: " << width << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Height: " << height << std::endl;

  // delete[] chunks;
}
```